# c# unity 3d coordinates map sync

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates, marching-cubes

I'm working on a procedurally generated map/game. I have 3D chunks with 20x20x20 points in a 3D array. I'm using marching cubes algorithm to generate the chunks. I try to manipulate the density with adding and subtracting the values but in the same time trying to sync the neighbour chunks edge together the with chunk im modifying.[image: adding density to a chunk's points]

Here is the code i tough it will work, but its not working:

```
`for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        Chunk nChunk = neighbours[i].GetComponent<Chunk>();
        if (i == 4) continue; //skip self
        for (int z = 0; z < 20; z += 19)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x += 19)
            {
                for (int zz = 0; zz < 20; zz += 19)
                {
                    for (int xx = 0; xx < 20; xx += 19)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
                        {
                            if (Points[xx, y, zz].wPosition == nChunk.Points[x, y, z].wPosition)
                                nChunk.Points[x, y, z].density = Points[xx, y, zz].density;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

I want to check the edges and not all Points to save performance. the y coords the height.

Here is how i call this:

```
        //mouse click
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray raym = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitm;
        if (Physics.Raycast(raym, out hitm))
        {
            if (hitm.transform.GetComponent<Chunk>())
            {
                Chunk cScript = hitm.transform.GetComponent<Chunk>();
                for (int z = 0; z < 20; z++)
                {
                    for (int y = 1; y < 19; y++)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
                        {
                            if (PointInsideSphere(cScript.Points[x, y, z].wPosition, hitm.point, 1f))
                                cScript.Points[x, y, z].density -= 0.1f;
                        }
                    }
                }
                cScript.SyncNeighbours();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

In this way its working good but i want to check only the edges.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        Chunk nChunk = neighbours[i].GetComponent<Chunk>();

        if (i == 4) continue; //skip self
        for (int z = 0; z < 20; z ++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x ++)
            {
                for (int zz = 0; zz < 20; zz ++)
                {
                    for (int xx = 0; xx < 20; xx ++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
                        {
                            if (Points[xx, y, zz].wPosition.x == nChunk.Points[x, y, z].wPosition.x && Points[xx, y, zz].wPosition.y == nChunk.Points[x, y, z].wPosition.y && Points[xx, y, zz].wPosition.z == nChunk.Points[x, y, z].wPosition.z)
                                nChunk.Points[x, y, z].density = Points[xx, y, zz].density;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        neighbours[j].GetComponent<Chunk>().UpdateChunk();
    }
```

Comment: in what way has it not worked?

Comment: no density changed in neighbour chunks. u think the for loops are right?

Comment: well looking at the code it seems confusing.  if you have 3d space (eg points [x,y,z] type) I would expect only 3 loops. to pick a spot (eg 0-19), and 3 loops to go round the spot.  as in x-1 to x+1, y-1 to y+1 and z-1 to z+1 assuming its not a hard edge eg x=0 or 19 etc. The variable naming doesnt entirely help . But on face value it seems you have more loops than you needed, but is making my head hurt a bit... given i dont have names for those methods and you mention circle you possibly then dont even need the x-1 to x+1 type loops to go round so should only need less..

Comment: i know what u mean but the world cordinates are different than local. with 3 loops i can check only local values i think.i must iterate through edges of both chunk. for example: neighbour(4) whih is the center of 9 chunks have 8 neighbours. if neighbour(4). x,y,z  [0,0,0] it means world cordinates are 0,0,0 for the point. but for the right neigbour(5) its: x,y,z = 20,0,0 at the same [0,0,0]. im not perfect in english and i hope u understand what i mean.

Comment: i have to iterate through of the edge of 2 chunks at the same time and compare their density. x,y loop goes around first chunk and xx,yy goes around second chunk edge points.

Comment: in a more similar way: i want to compare two 3d array edges. and update the first array to same values in the second.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved in different way: When the game creates a chunk it checks points with 0 and 19 positions in 3d array then add them to a list. from that list i can check the points on neighbouring faces and make the densitys equal.